# How to write the data to excel file located in computer D drive in Android test project using AndroidWebDriver?

Tags: android, android-emulator, selenium-webdriver, robotium

**Code:**

```
String xf = "D:/AndroidResults/Results.xls";
        File outFile = new File(xf); 
        FileInputStream myStream1 = new FileInputStream(outFile);
        HSSFWorkbook myWBook = new HSSFWorkbook (myStream1);
        HSSFSheet oSheet = myWBook.getSheet("Results"); 
        HSSFRow row = oSheet.getRow(rowNum); 
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(xlData);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        myWBook.write(fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
```

**Exception:**

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /D:/AndroidResults/Results.xls (No such file or directory)`

May be its trying to find out the file in mobile device instead of computer. But how to handle this situation where I have to write the data to excel located in my computer.

Please help.

Thanks,
D

Comment: The thing is that the way you are doing this work is not the right way.

Comment: Ali, now I am trying to keep the excel in the mobile device and trying to write the data into it. Its working fine but every time we need to pull the file from the device using DDMS to our machine. Is there any way we can pull this file automatically to machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb pull command. Make a batch file and write this command adb pull "path of local folder" "path of DDMS". You are just a double click away to see the file.